# I've tried running this code for plotting the figure in matlab, but it gives the following error, what will be the solution?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

```
function plotData(x, y)
figure;
plot(x, y, 'rx', 'MarkerSize', 10);
ylabel('Profit in $10,000s');
xlabel('Population of City in 10,000s');
end
```

I have this code but still I'm getting an error saying plotData requires more arguments to run on line 3.

what's the solution to this?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly so not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

You're right. that's because when you run your function Matlab will show an error and it says "Not input arguments".
That's not mean that your code is wrong. give some input to your function and you will see result. for example try this:

```
plotData([1,2,4,5],[1,2,3,4])
```

surely you will see that your code run correctly.